# DISTINCT clause on string column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, distinct

I used the sql query on MySQL database:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT Sp_Name,
  CONCAT('SP_',Sp_Id) AS searchPayerId
FROM  
  ServiceProviders 
WHERE 
  Comp_Id= 3 
  AND Sp_Id NOT IN (1,2)
  AND Sp_Name != ''
GROUP BY 
  Sp_Id
```

still I am getting follow output. why this duplicate '001 Towing'?

```
Sp_Name                                 searchPayerId
-----------------------------------------------------
#1 24 Hour Emergency Towing                SP_50094
'Triple T' Pts&Equip/Warsaw                SP_65699
0 00 Anytime Towing                        SP_50095
0 00 Anywhere Towing                   SP_50096
001 Towing                                 SP_50097
001 Towing                                 SP_50098
001 Towing                                 SP_50099
001 Towing                                 SP_50100
1 - 800 - Tow - Help Inc.                  SP_55040
1 2 3 Towing                           SP_27761
1 24 Hour Affordable Towing                SP_50101
```

I would like to get follow output:

```
   Sp_Name                              searchPayerId

-----------------------------------------------------
#1 24 Hour Emergency Towing                SP_50094
'Triple T' Pts&Equip/Warsaw                SP_65699
0 00 Anytime Towing                        SP_50095
0 00 Anywhere Towing                   SP_50096
001 Towing                                 SP_50097_50098_50099_50100
1 - 800 - Tow - Help Inc.                  SP_55040
1 2 3 Towing                           SP_27761
1 24 Hour Affordable Towing                SP_50101
```

How can I get it?

Comment: what your desired output?

Comment: it is duplicated because DISTINCT refers to the whole set of columns, not only to Sp_Name. Also your query is not standard SQL but it will only work on MySql. In case that SP_Name is duplicated, which player id do you want to get? SP_50097, SP_50099, ... or SP_50100 ?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword applies to the complete row in the result set. MySQL will not remove arbitrary rows for you (well, not at least in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting a duplicate "001 Towing", **the distinct is applied to each group generated by the group by clause**. Therefore, you get 4 x "001 Towing" one for each "Sp_Id"; if you remove the group by, you will get only one "001 Towing".

You made the wrong question to the database, and the database gave you the right answer to your wrong question. If you tell us what the query is supposed to do, we might be able to help you fix it...

---

for your new specification try this query, it should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  Sp_Name as Sp_Name,
   CONCAT('SP_', **group_concat ( Sp_Id separator '_ ' )** ) as searchPayerId
FROM  
  ServiceProviders 
WHERE 
  Comp_Id= 3 
  AND Sp_Id NOT IN (1,2)
  AND Sp_Name != ''
**GROUP BY 
  Sp_Name**
```

---

BTW you can look in the mySQL manual how the [Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) works, and the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)...

Comment: I have modified question for desired output

Comment: @SQL.injection what is the difference between mine answer and your answer logic wise change it so  it doesn't like a copy paste

Comment: @dianuj if you look careful you will noticed i used **group_concat** and you didn't.

Comment: @SQL.injection what it makes only effects `searchPayerId` which is not the required for the answer :)

Comment: @dianuj how exactly does your query generates something like this: "001 Towing                                 SP_50097_50098_50099_50100"?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `GROUP BY` with `Sp_Id` and `DISTINCT` on Sp_Name  you have to `GROUP BY` the results using `Sp_Name` like

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Sp_Id,
Sp_Name,
CONCAT('SP_',Sp_Id) AS searchPayerId
FROM  
ServiceProviders 
WHERE 
Comp_Id= 3 
AND Sp_Id NOT IN (1,2)
AND Sp_Name != ''
GROUP BY 
Sp_Name
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00bd1c/1)
Hope it makes sense